# SAP .Net Connector 3 and Single Sign on

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

I am using SAP .net Connector 3.0 for my connection from my app to sap and I have gotten everything working ok but now my company has switched to Single Sign on.

I done a little reading and so far I found I have to set the following parameters in the Destination Configuration.

```
RfcConfigParameters.SncMode
RfcConfigParameters.SncPartnerName
```

Does anyone know what I set these parameters too?

EDIT:
Looks like I have the information for me to solve my problem but if anyone wants to add comments as to what the 2 parameters are and what the options are then go ahead.

```
RfcConfigParameters.SncMode     // I set this to = "1", read you can set to "2", not sure the differnce
RfcConfigParameters.SncPartnerName   // Under the SAP login screen which has the list of servers
                                     // if you right click the one you want and select 
                                     // properties -> Network the SncPartnerName is 
                                     // the SNC Name which starts with p:
```

Comment: From what I can remember, SncMode is also settable to 4 and 8, and are to do with whether to force snc on/off, choose based on the server setting etc. They're all detailed in the SAP NCO 3.0 documentation, which you'll need to have a SAP Service Marketplace account to access (I don't have access any more so can't tell you myself)

Answer (score 0):

0 and null mean SNC mode is off. Any other value is on. I have seen values 1 and 8 used in different online postings.
You can find this both in the SAP .NET Connector 3.0 (NCo 3.0) help file under "RfcDestination..::SncMode Property" remarks as well as in the .NET connector 3.0 programming guide here:

https://support.sap.com/content/dam/support/en_us/library/ssp/products/connectors/msnet/dotnet_connector_30_programming_guide.pdf

(It could be you need a SAP market place SSO to open this link.)

So there is no difference of meaning between 1, 2, 4 or 8 (likely a legacy of bit offset).